# SVG stroke-width is weird when x=0, y=0

Tags: svg

I'm learning `SVG`. As we know, `svg` use `border-box` as box-sizing default. But when I try to add `stroke` to a `svg`, and put the `svg` in the initial postion - by setting `x=0` and `y=0`. The `svg` seems not like a `border-box` strictly.

```xml
<svg width="320px" height="320px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="30">
</svg>
```

The effect is in here:

https://codepen.io/Aklscc/pen/XWWRPzm

And When I set `x` and `y` to a bigger number than 30, it works well. So, what's the rational?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X and Y coordinates define the middle of the "stroke" so when you start at `X=0` and/or `Y=0` half the width of the line is cut off.

Move your rectangle to `x="10" y="10"` and you will see more in the upper right. You don't need to go to `x="30" y="30"`, since your stroke width is `30` you only need to change the location to anything greater than `x="15" y="15"`and you will see the whole rectangle.